# GCP Log Cost Attribution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging

I have multiple service on a single project, lets say i have 2 GAE (Google App Engine)
The first one is **service_a** and the second one is **service_b**. Both service write logs. I've already label both GAE, but it's seems the label is not included the log cost. Is there any way to differentiate the log cost between **service_a** and **service_b**?

Comment: How long since you created the labels? You must wait until the next billing cycle.

Comment: @JohnHanley, more than 3 months
fyi, this is happened on all service e.g GAE, Cloud Dataflow, Cloud Function,Cloud run, etc

Comment: Are you exporting the billing data to BigQuery? This [link](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/bq-examples#query-with-labels) shows how to query based on labels.

Comment: Can you refer to this [audit logs estimate costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/audit-log-estimate-costs) and [Cloud Logging pricing summary](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#logging-costs) which might help you in understanding the Log cost. You can also try by using this [Price calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=), In this Calculator search for  `Cloud Operations product` and enter the values it is asking. Here, you should know the volumes of logs data  received to a service.  By entering these data values,we can know the log cost of each service.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how much the logs cost for each service? I am not aware of a standard method to do that. The pricing for Cloud Logging is per GB. The Cloud Logging cost details are not broken down by service.

Comment: @JohnHanley,
>Are you trying to figure out how much the logs cost for each service? 
yes exactly, so currently there are no solution for this?

Comment: You would need to process each log entry, estimate its size, figure out which service sent the log, and tabulate. Google Cloud does not provide a service that does what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after wasting my time for few days
i've found alternative solution for this

on default, you will have 2 log storage & 2 log router sink

1. _Default
2. _Required (ignore this)

from my understanding

1. log storage is a storage that will store your log
2. log router sink is a rule that will decided where the log will be stored

on default, your log will be store on _Default log

here the default state on terraform

```
resource "google_logging_project_bucket_config" "_Default" {
  project        = data.google_project.project.project_id
  location       = "global"
  retention_days = 30
  bucket_id      = "_Default"
  description    = "Default"
}

resource "google_logging_project_sink" "_default" {
  name        = "_Default"
  disabled    = false
  destination = "logging.googleapis.com/projects/my-project/locations/global/buckets/_Default"

  filter = "NOT LOG_ID(\"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"externalaudit.googleapis.com/activity\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/system_event\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"externalaudit.googleapis.com/system_event\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/access_transparency\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"externalaudit.googleapis.com/access_transparency\")"


  unique_writer_identity = true
}
```

So the solution is by create the log storage and log router sink for each your service,
you can look terraform code below (this case, i have 1 GAE and 1 Dataflow)

```
resource "google_logging_project_bucket_config" "_Default" {
  project        = data.google_project.project.project_id
  location       = "global"
  retention_days = 30
  bucket_id      = "_Default"
  description    = "Default"
}

resource "google_logging_project_bucket_config" "ingestion_dataflow_logging_bucket" {
  project        = data.google_project.project.project_id
  location       = "global"
  retention_days = 30
  bucket_id      = "ingestion_dataflow"
  description    = "ingestion dataflow logging bucket"
}

resource "google_logging_project_bucket_config" "gae_minerva_logging_bucket" {
  project        = data.google_project.project.project_id
  location       = "global"
  retention_days = 30
  bucket_id      = "gae_minerva"
  description    = "gae minerva logging bucket"
}

resource "google_logging_project_sink" "_default" {
  name        = "_Default"
  disabled    = false
  destination = "logging.googleapis.com/projects/my-project/locations/global/buckets/_Default"

  filter = "NOT LOG_ID(\"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/activity\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"externalaudit.googleapis.com/activity\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/system_event\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"externalaudit.googleapis.com/system_event\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"cloudaudit.googleapis.com/access_transparency\") AND NOT LOG_ID(\"externalaudit.googleapis.com/access_transparency\")"

  exclusions {
    name     = "dataflow-ingestion-exclusions"
    disabled = false
    filter   = "resource.type=\"dataflow_step\" AND jsonPayload.worker:\"dataflow_ingestion_worker\""
  }
  exclusions {
    name     = "gae-minerva-exclusions"
    disabled = false
    filter   = "resource.type=\"gae_app\" AND resource.labels.module_id:\"minerva_project\""
  }

  unique_writer_identity = true
}

resource "google_logging_project_sink" "ingestion_dataflow_logging_sink" {
  name        = "ingestion_dataflow"
  disabled    = false
  destination = "logging.googleapis.com/projects/my-project/locations/global/buckets/ingestion_dataflow"

  filter = "resource.type=\"dataflow_step\" AND jsonPayload.worker:\"dataflow_ingestion_worker\""

  unique_writer_identity = true
}

resource "google_logging_project_sink" "gae_minerva_logging_sink" {
  name        = "gae_minerva"
  disabled    = false
  destination = "logging.googleapis.com/projects/my-project/locations/global/buckets/gae_minerva"

  filter                 = "resource.type=\"gae_app\" AND resource.labels.module_id:\"minerva_project\""
  unique_writer_identity = true
}
```

by creating storage bucket for each services, you can see the log size. therefore you can estimate the log cost for each service

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by exploring this [Price Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=) as a workaround. In this Calculator search for `cloud Operations product` and enter the values it is asking. Here, you should know the volumes of logs data  received to a service.  By entering these data values , we can know the log cost of each service.

Below is an example given for your reference :

If **service A** received 100 Gib volume of logs then we need to enter the value as shown in the below screenshot- 1.

[image: screenshot-1]

Post entering the value and then clicking on estimate we will receive the estimated cost as shown in below screenshot-2.

[image: Screenshot-2]

Similarly we need to check for the **Service B**. This is just a suggestion for your query

And also As per @JohnHanley comments, if there is no such method. **Raise this as a feature request at the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)** report with the description of your issue . This Issue Tracker is a forum for end users to report bugs and request features to improve google cloud products. Product engineering from Google will work on this implementation.